# I got the error: The method 'getCurrentRecording' isn't defined for the type 'MicrophoneRecorder'

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, dart

```
Visibility(
            visible: isRecording == false,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final recording = await _recorder.getCurrentRecording();
                if (recording != null) {
                  await _audioPlayer.play(recording.path);
                }
              },
```

> Error: The method 'getCurrentRecording' isn't defined for the type 'MicrophoneRecorder'.

What should I do?

I tried upgrading the microphone package and executed the flutter clean command

Comment: I suppose you're using https://pub.dev/packages/microphone library ?

Answer (score 0):

On [microphone library docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/microphone/latest/microphone/microphone-library.html) there doesn't seem to be a method definition for `getCurrentRecording`, which most probably is the reason why you're facing this issue. You can find all the supported methods for `MicrophoneRecorder` at [MicrophoneRecorder Class Docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/microphone/latest/microphone/MicrophoneRecorder-class.html).

That said, in order to retrieve the recording you could use the below:

1. Record something, and then stop the recording (this is just an example here, most probably you need to use some logic to achieve that - i.e., 2 buttons to start and stop the recording etc).

```
_recorder.start();
// record something in between
_recorder.stop();
```

2. Retrieve the recording

```
_audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
await _audioPlayer.setUrl(_recorder.value.recording.url);
await _audioPlayer.play();
```

There is a very nice example application demonstrating the microphone library on [GitHub: microphone example app](https://github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/microphone/blob/main/microphone/example/lib/main.dart). It can give some ideas on how to utilize the package.

Hope it helps.

Cheers,
Ioannis